# How to set background to black

Tags: android, themes

Whie I set activity theme to light.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

And I set layout background to 0x000000.
It will display gray.
How to make it to　black?

I set below line to color.xml.
  #000000
And set as below:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
```

ll is LinearLayout.

Comment: Are you sure it's grey? How did you set it?

Comment: I set as the modify in question.

Comment: I found the error. It should be set by setBackgroundResource.

Comment: You could use `setBackgroundColor()` but with an actual color, not the id. `setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `#ff000000` instead of `#000000`. Try this:

```
//Try one of these lines:
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ff000000"));
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

//Or change your color.xml value to #ff000000 and use
ll.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
```